target is not found by stimulus controller
On my page, I have 2 tables with the same business rules and structure. Using my controller on the first table works as expected, it finds all the html elements. But on the second table, it fails to find the input field the event listener is assigned to.
We have the "no-duplicate-table" controller on the partent <th:block>.
In that controller we listen to changes on "no-duplicate-table.input", on every change we check if that value is already in the "no-duplicate-table.table", if that's the case, we show an error.
 <th:block th:if="${isMgmtQualifierConfigured}">
                    <div id="managementQualifiers" class="iv-ui-data-table vl-u-spacer" data-target="page2json.table"
                         data-controller="editable-table no-duplicates-table">
                        <div class="iv-ui-data-table--actions vl-u-spacer">
                            <button th:if="${recording.canEdit}"
                                    class="vl-button" data-target="editable-table.newLineButton"
                                    data-action="click->editable-table#toggleInputs"
                                    th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.action.new}"
                                    autofocus></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="iv-ui-data-table--inputs" data-target="editable-table.inputsContainer"
                             data-controller="drill-down" data-drill-down-id="qualifier"
                             data-drill-down-label="Qualifier" data-drill-down-child-id="specific"
                             data-drill-down-child-label="Specifiek"
                             th:data-drill-down-parent-action-group="${mgmtQualifierActionGroup}"
                             th:data-drill-down-parent-list-name="${mgmtQualifierListName}">
                            <form data-target="drill-down.form">
                                <div class="iv-ui-data-table vl-u-spacer vl-u-bg-alt">
                                    <div class="vl-u-visually-hidden">
                                        <input name="id" type="hidden"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <th:block th:if="${mgmtQualifierPeriodInputList != null}">
                                        <div class="iv-form-field">
                                            <div class="iv-input-field" data-controller="input-toggle"
                                                 data-input-toggle-active="true"
                                                 data-target="input-toggle.primaryValue"
                                                 data-input-toggle-checkbox-name="period.fromList"
                                                 data-input-toggle-value-field-name="period.value">
                                                <input class="vl-u-visually-hidden" type="hidden" name="period.fromList" value="true"/>
                                                <label class="vl-form__label iv-ui-required-label"
                                                       for="period.value" id="mgmtQualifier.period"
                                                       th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.period}"></label>
                                                <div class="vl-input-group" data-target="input-toggle.primaryGroup">
                                                    <select class="vl-select"
                                                            id="period.value" name="period.value"
                                                            aria-labelledby="mgmtQualifier.period"
                                                            data-target="input-toggle.primaryValue no-duplicates-table.input"
                                                            data-activated="true"
                                                            data-required="true">
                                                        <option value=""></option>
                                                        <option th:each="item : ${mgmtQualifierPeriodInputList}"
                                                                th:value="${item.code}"
                                                                th:text="${item.code + ' - ' + item.description}"></option>
                                                    </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="vl-form__error"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </th:block>
                                    <div class="iv-ui-data-table--actions">
                                        <button class="vl-button" type="button"
                                                data-target="no-duplicates-table.confirmNewLineButton"
                                                data-action="click->editable-table#editOrInsertData">
                                            Toevoegen
                                        </button>
                                        <button class="vl-button" type="button"
                                                data-action="click->editable-table#resetAndHideInputs">
                                            Annuleren
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="vl-form__error"
                                 data-target="no-duplicates-table.error"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="iv-ui-data-table--data">
                            <div class="vl-u-table-overflow">
                                <table id="mgmtqualifier-table" class="vl-data-table vl-data-table--zebra"
                                       data-target="editable-table.data no-duplicates-table.table">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr class="vl-data-table__header">
                                        <th class="vl-u-visually-hidden"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="id"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="HIDDEN">
                                            ID
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-u-visually-hidden"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="period.fromList"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="HIDDEN">
                                            FromList
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="period.value"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="INPUT_TOGGLE"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.period}">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="qualifier"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="SELECT"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.qualifier}">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="specific"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="SELECT"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.specific}">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="notSure"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="CHECKBOX"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.not-sure}">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="indirect"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="CHECKBOX"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.indirect}">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            data-form-attribute-name="elucidation"
                                            data-form-attribute-type="TEXT"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.elucidation}">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="vl-data-table__header-title"
                                            th:text="#{recording.management-qualifier.actions}"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </th:block>

Here is the stimulus controller
export class NoDuplicatesTableController extends Controller {

    static targets = ["input","table","error","confirmNewLineButton"];

    connect() {
        this.inputTarget.addEventListener('input', (event) => this.validate(event));
    }

    validate(event) {
        const inputValue = this.inputTarget.value;
        const rows = Array.from(this.tableTarget.rows).slice(1); // Exclude header row

        const duplicates = rows.filter(row => row.cells[2].textContent === inputValue);

        if (duplicates.length > 0) {
            this.errorTarget.textContent = "Input value already exists in the table.";
            this.confirmNewLineButtonTarget.disabled = true;
        } else {
            this.errorTarget.textContent = "";
            this.confirmNewLineButtonTarget.disabled = false;
        }
    }
}

But here, when inspecting "this.inputTarget" is empty, it can't find a target named "input". But it does work on a sibling th:block, same structure

The problem likely arises from the controller not correctly handling multiple instances or targets.hope this help you if not inform me to try any possible solutions
try this:
//in connect method get all input target
connect() {
this.inputTargets.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('input', (event) => this.validate(event, input));
  });
}

//in validate method get second parameter
alidate(event, input) {
 const inputValue = input.value;
 // Get the specific table target within the scope of this controller instance
 const table = this.tableTarget;
 const rows = Array.from(table.rows).slice(1); // Exclude header row
 const duplicates = rows.filter(row => row.cells[2].textContent === inputValue)
// ...and rest of your code
}


I read that every mention of a controller returns a different instance

The array has a length of 1, from the first th:block, not this one

@ThomasE let me check your html file to ensure unique identifiers.

https://codefile.io/f/g5rgRioJmn if we find a solution I will share the part of the code that caused it. But it's too long according to stackoverlfow
